# Is there anyway to get the "watermark" value in the bot builder?

Tags: node.js, botframework, backend, watermark

I have a webchat for a user connected to the bot through directline.

I want a second user to join to the same conversation, but I want the second user to be able to read the full conversation.

Right now when the second user connects to the conversation it doesn't see anything of the first user conversation because he doesn't join with a watermark value.

I have this code on **bot builder v4** right now:

```
const options = {
   method: 'GET',
   uri: 'https://myuri/addRow?conversationId='+stepContext.context.activity.conversation.id,
};
await req-promise(options);
```

I would like to send something like this:

```
const options = {
   method: 'GET',
   uri: 'https://myuri/addRow?conversationId='+stepContext.context.activity.conversation.id+'watermark='+watermark,
};
await req-promise(options);
```

Is there anyway to get that watermark value?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Per this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS/issues/185).

> The cache of messages in the Direct Line connector service is intended to be used as a connection reliability mechanism, not as an actual message history store.
>   If you require more granular control over conversation history, you will need implement an a transcript store server side.  And, you can use the [SendConversationHistoryAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.connector.conversationsextensions.sendconversationhistoryasync) api to send chunks of history messages to the conversation.
>   We do not currently have a complete example demonstrating this, but it is in the works.

I would recommend using a [transcript logger](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/TranscriptLoggerMiddleware.cs) to store and manage your own conversation history instead of trying to pull the messages from the cache. Also, if you try to use the watermark, you'll run into permission issues since one conversation doesn't have the ability to see another conversation's data.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just need to connect to a conversation that I know is open. I just found that I don't need to get the watermark in the bot builder, I can do it from the webchat, just joining the conversation with the watermark "0" I'm able to see the full conversation.

Comment: Great! Glad you found a workable solution. If you need more details, I would recommend taking a look at these two GitHub issues. https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2059 https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2116